# File permissions changed after SFTP

Tags: permissions, sftp

I just transferred files and folders from my local machine to my web server using SFTP.

Doing `ls -l` on both machines indicates file and folder permissions seems to have changed.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New files copied over are generally given a filter through the `umask` when written to a new location.  To preserve the permissions as at the source, use `scp -p` (see also `cp -p`; `rsync -p`).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm assuming `scp -p` means copy and preserve? May I ask what exactly is preserved?

Comment: The `-p` generally (and specifically in the case of `scp`) preserves modification times, access times, and modes (aka permissions) from the source file.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to provide the `-p` info :)

Comment: aswell as mask, many ftp/sftp/ftps daemons will attempt to set permissions either to same as local or more typically a pre-defined permission within the tool. scp does not do this though, it will allow the remote server to define the permissions of the file through masks.

Comment: @mikejonesey I just want permissions to remain the same

Comment: depends on the client you are using, for scp there is "-p" guys at work here use one called cyberduck (mac users), in that client there is a checkbox to disable the default option which is to override permissions with a preset value.

Comment: I think I will use `scp -p`. Thanks for the info